# Messaging between users with node application

Tags: node.js, encryption, message

I want to implement in-app messaging in my iOS and Android application, and I am unsure about how the backend functionality should be created. From before my backend is running with Node.js and users etc. are stored with MongoDB.

I figure that I quite easily could implement messaging just by saving the messages in the database and sending a push to the recipient with the new message and also showing it in the app, but I do not want the messages to be readable on the server. It would therefore be necessary to encrypt them in the database and decrypt them on the clients.

Do anyone have any suggestions for either how the encryption could be implemented or about node frameworks to use? I have looked at socket.io, but this seem to be created for real time chatting applications, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. I have also looked at RabbitMQ, but I don't really understand if it suits my requirements or not.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about end to end encryption. Your encryption would be easy to break if the key for the encryption is hardcoded inside the application. In order to implement something like this, you'll need a library for iOS and a library for Android.

For iOS, I recommend using OpenSSL and implementing a encryption scheme(Public key Cryptography). For Android, you can use the Spongy Castle library.

Due to limitations with iOS push notification size, it is not a great idea to send data via PUSH. 
You will also (probably)need to implement a authentication mechanism for users to login. 
You can go on two paths here..

1. Have the server generate a secret for the clients to decrypt
2. Separate keys, (hashed password on database, and public/privatekeys on client)

I have not used socket.io/rabbitmq, so unfortunately I cannot help you there. It seems like you are new to this, I would take a good look & reading on public key cryptography. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Examples

Comment: Sounds like a great plant. Cheers!